# Headline adjustment

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

How can I adjust the chapter headline, so that the last line ends with the red box? And is there a way to move the whole chapter heading so that the word "chapter" is adjusted with the main text, i.e. so that the upper side of the letters "chapters" is adjusted to the text body below?

```
\documentclass[             fontsize=12pt,
                            % monochrome,
                             a4paper,               
                             parskip=half,      
                             ngerman,
                             headinclude=true,
                             footinclude=false,
                             captions=tableheading,
                             numbers=noenddot,
                             headings=big]
                             %chapterprefix=true]   % 
                            {scrreprt}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Define own Chapter style
% Pretty chapter pages
%------------------------------------------
\definecolor{nicered}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter}
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
\sbox\feline@chapter{%
\resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
\colorbox{nicered}{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
}}%
\rotatebox{90}{%
\resizebox{%
\heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}%
{!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
\raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
}
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
\sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{% aka \rlap
\makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
}}   

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\hspace{\leftmargin} \feline@chm[2.5cm] % Height of the colored box
\hspace{2cm}
}
\makeatother
%------------------------------------------

\begin{document}


\chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: I've addressed the first issue in my answer below. I, however, don't understand the second part. Could you please explain in more detail (adding an image even if hand-drawn would be ideal) what exactly should be the desired position of the "Chapter" string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option patching `\@@makechapterhead`:

```
\documentclass[             fontsize=12pt,
                            % monochrome,
                             a4paper,               
                             parskip=half,      
                             ngerman,
                             headinclude=true,
                             footinclude=false,
                             captions=tableheading,
                             numbers=noenddot,
                             headings=big]
                             %chapterprefix=true]   % 
                            {scrreprt}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Define own Chapter style
% Pretty chapter pages
%------------------------------------------
\definecolor{nicered}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter}
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
\sbox\feline@chapter{%
\resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
\colorbox{nicered}{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
}}%
\rotatebox{90}{%
\resizebox{%
\heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}%
{!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
\raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
}
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
\sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{% aka \rlap
\makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
}}   

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\hspace{\leftmargin} \feline@chm[2.5cm] % Height of the colored box
\hspace{2cm}
}

\patchcmd{\@@makechapterhead}
  {\size@chapter{#1}}
  {\size@chapter{\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-4cm\relax}{\raggedright#1}}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
%------------------------------------------

\begin{document}


\chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, there is another issue - the colorbox command doesn't center the chapter number is there a way to force the centering of the chapter number (in the red box)? I planed with fbox and \struct but it doesn't really work as I hoped.

Comment: @harryhaller You're welcome. I don't seem to see a problem with the centering. Can you please provide the code for a small document showing the problem mentioned?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina With an new version of KOMA-script and texlive 2015 I get the heading at the foot of the "1" and not vertically centered to the height of the "1".

Answer (score 1):

With KOMA-Script Version 3.19a or newer you can redefine `\chapterlinesformat`:

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=12pt,
  a4paper,
  parskip=half,
  ngerman,
  headinclude=true,
  footinclude=false,
  captions=tableheading,
  numbers=noenddot,
  headings=big
]{scrreprt}[2015/10/03]

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%------------------------------------------
\definecolor{nicered}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter}
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
  \sbox\feline@chapter{%
    \resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
      \colorbox{nicered}{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
    }%
  }%
  \rotatebox{90}{%
    \resizebox{%
      \heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
      }{!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}
  \raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
  \hspace*{1.5ex}
}
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
  \sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}%
  \usebox\feline@chapter%
}   
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\feline@chm[2.5cm]}
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
    #2\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\feline@chapter\relax}{\raggedchapter#3}%
}
\makeatother
%------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]