# Change the word "Chapter"

Tags: sectioning, naming

I'm using the following code and the question is, how can I change the word "Chapter" for "Chapitre" (in French)? Thanks in advance!:

```
\documentclass[             fontsize=12pt,
                            % monochrome,
                             a4paper,               
                             parskip=half,      
                             ngerman,
                             headinclude=true,
                             footinclude=false,
                             captions=tableheading,
                             numbers=noenddot,
                             headings=big]
                             %chapterprefix=true]   % 
                            {scrreprt}

\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Define own Chapter style
% Pretty chapter pages
%------------------------------------------
\definecolor{nicered}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter}
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
\sbox\feline@chapter{%
\resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
\colorbox{nicered}{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
}}%
\rotatebox{90}{%
\resizebox{%
\heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}%
{!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
\raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
}
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
\sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{% aka \rlap
\makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
}}   

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\hspace{\leftmargin} \feline@chm[2.5cm] % Height of the colored box
\hspace{2cm}
}

\patchcmd{\@@makechapterhead}
  {\size@chapter{#1}}
  {\size@chapter{\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-4cm\relax}{\raggedright#1}}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
%------------------------------------------

\begin{document}


\chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't repreoduce your issue: the code compiles fine and localized, i.e. it says "chapitre".

Comment: @DG' Weird. I get "Font" warnings unless I comment out his preamble.

Comment: @Alenanno I get warnings too but in the end it says CHAPITRE....

Comment: @DG' Where? I don't get any output because of the warnings. :D

Comment: I see it localized, but the appearance is definitely not right. Which KOMA-versions are you running?

Comment: Works on: Frozen TL2014 with scrreprt 2015/02/07 v3.16

Comment: @DG' sorry, false alarm, my buffer introduced a newline and a comment got in the way. It works with `scrreprt 2015/05/19 v3.18.2105` just fine, the localisation as well.

Comment: brw, you can always rename stuff in your document with `\renewcaptionname{french}{\chaptername}{Zelev}` as explained in [How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography" etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993)

Comment: The MWE is taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/194289/ looks like the question is simply who to localize Chapternames and has nothing to do with the MWE. Like @Johannes_B said: `\renewcaptionname` should do the trick